# Hide mouse cursor in client area with delay?

Tags: c, winapi, user-experience

I am writing a Windows application in C.

I am hiding the mouse cursor in the client area of the window by handling the `WM_SETCURSOR` message:

```
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
    {
        static BOOL HideCursor = FALSE;
        if ((LOWORD(LParam) == HTCLIENT) && !HideCursor)
        {
            HideCursor = TRUE;
            ShowCursor(FALSE);
        }
        else if ((LOWORD(LParam) != HTCLIENT) && HideCursor)
        {
            HideCursor = FALSE;
            ShowCursor(TRUE);
        }
        Result = DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam);
        break;
    }
```

This works fine, but it is a little awkward, because the mouse cursor disappears instantly as soon as it crosses into the client area of the window. The user can easily lose track of where the mouse cursor "should be" when he or she is trying to move the cursor toward the toolbar buttons, or manually resize the window, for example.

How can I add a second or two of delay in there so that the user can move the mouse over the client area of the window without the mouse instantly disappearing, but if the mouse cursor hovers in the client area for more than a second or two, it disappears?

Comment: Just set a timer to hide the cursor instead of hiding the cursor.

Comment: can you not just use the delay(); function?

Comment: BTW "I am writing a Windows application in C" - bad idea, just because you could doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @DomAdams if by delay() you mean sleep() then you do NOT want to do that when processing a message; all message processing will stop, which has negative effects (and in the case of the delayed hiding cursor, won't respond to mouse movements).

Comment: @ddriver what do you suggest then

Comment: @andlabs - any other language will be easier and faster to work in. C is way too low level for application development.

Comment: Just because other languages are easier and faster to work in (which I do agree with) does not mean C is totally useless. I do all my Windows API work in C, and there's a huge library of advanced software (including *much of Windows itself*) written in plain C. C may be too low level but that doesn't mean it's not high level enough. This is different from, say, writing large and complex Windows programs in assembly language. That's not saying much either; there are a lot of asm programmers (and I sometimes envy their patience with the x86 ISA). You use what you prefer to use.

Comment: @andlabs - but you don't have constructors, destructors, templates, virtual methods, inheritance, polymorphism and exception handling, not even basic containers - all stuff which is often heavily used in application development, and all stuff which is utterly tedious and time consuming to do manually, on top of opening extra room for bugs. 

And besides, I didn't say C is "useless", just that for application development it is a bad idea, for the above mentioned reasons. Plus you can still directly use the MS C APIs with C++. C is OK for system APIs, but for applications is far too suboptimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are notified that the mouse cursor entered the window, you could use `SetTimer(hWnd, ID_MOUSE_TIMER, 2000, NULL)` where `hWnd` is your window handle and `ID_MOUSE_TIMER` is an arbitrary identifier for a timer, to create a timer that will fire after 2000 milliseconds.

You can then respond to the `WM_TIMER` message and hide the cursor just as you did before, but also use `KillTimer(hWnd, ID_MOUSE_TIMER)` to prevent further calls.

When the mouse cursor leaves your window, you should also destroy the timer, and also restore visibility of the mouse cursor if it was hidden just as you did before.

To read up on timers, check the corresponding [section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468913.aspx) in the MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [WM_MOUSEHOVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Comment: This is the better solution, not only because it uses existing implementation offered by Windows but also because Windows will count down the timeout only while the mouse is not moving. +1